# RSpec view test ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to get my RSpec view tests to pass and am getting the above error. From searching, I believe it's a problem with nested routes, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Here is the full error:

```
programs/show
  renders attributes in <p> (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) programs/show renders attributes in <p>
     Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       No route matches {:action=>"sort_cycles", :controller=>"programs", :id=>nil}
```

The line it's complaining about in the code is:

```
<ul class="cycles" data-update-url="<%= sort_cycles_program_url(params[:id]) %>" >
```

The test looks like:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "programs/show" do
  before(:each) do
    FactoryGirl.create(:goal)
    FactoryGirl.create(:experience_level)
    @program = FactoryGirl.create(:program)
  end

  it "renders attributes in <p>" do
    render
    rendered.should match(/Name/)
    rendered.should match(/Gender/)
    rendered.should match(Goal.find(@program.goal_id).name)
    rendered.should match(ExperienceLevel.find(@program.experience_id).name)
  end
end
```

and the route looks like this:

```
resources :programs do
    member { post :sort_cycles }
    resources :cycles_programs do
    end
  end
```

The sort_cycles action in the `ProgramsController`

```
def sort_cycles
    params[:cycles_program].each_with_index do |cycle_program_id, index|
      cycle_program = CyclesProgram.find(cycle_program_id)
      cycle_program.cycle_order = index+1
      cycle_program.save
    end
    render nothing: true
  end
```

EDIT:

Here is the full block of code from the view:

```
<ul class="cycles" data-update-url="<%= sort_cycles_program_url(params[:id]) %>" >
  <% @program.cycles_programs.each do |program| %>
    <%= content_tag_for :li, program, class: "cycle-block" do %>
      <%= link_to program.cycle.name, program.cycle %> | <%= link_to "Remove", program_cycles_program_path(@program, program), method: :delete %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: What does `rake routes` show you for the `sort_cycles` path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have written it, `sort_cycles_program_url(params[:id])` will route to the `sort_cycles` action within `ProgramsController`.  There could be a number of things failing here, so make sure you have them all correct:

1. Have a `sort_cycles` action defined within `ProgramsController`
2. Have a `sort_cycles.html.erb` template in `views/programs` unless you are rendering a different template (It's unclear as to where your HTML code above is placed)
3. Make sure your `sort_cycles` action can handle `params[:id] == nil`, since that's what you're giving it

Comment: To answer your first question, `rake routes` for `sort_cycles` gives `sort_cycles_program POST     /programs/:id/sort_cycles(.:format)                            programs#sort_cycles`

Comment: there is a `sort_cycles` action defined within the `ProgramsController` I updated the question with that code. And, `sort_cycles` is used to allow the user to drag and reorder a list of "cycles" using jquery `.sortable` and have the new order save to the database. The functionality does work.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe try `sort_cycles_program_path` instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "Make sure your `sort_cycles` action can handle `params[:id] == nil?`" Could this be what is causing the test to fail?  I also updated the question again with the full code block that is causing the test to fail.

Comment: "Hmmm, maybe try sort_cycles_program_path instead?" where?

Comment: ohh, you mean instead of `sort_cycles_program_url`

Comment: Nope, no change. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong in my test code only.

Comment: Ok, I got it working by changing `<ul class="cycles" data-update-url="<%= sort_cycles_program_url(params[:id]) %>" >` to `<ul class="cycles" data-update-url="<%= sort_cycles_program_url(@program.id) %>" >`. Switching to `params[:id]` to `@program.id` returns the same result, a url with the program id in it, but won't ever return nil.